# Dicionário com loop FOR em Python

Tags: python-3.x

Enquanto estudo Python, hora ou outra desenrolo meus próprios exercícios. Só que dessa vez eu 'empaquei' quando resolvi fazer o código abaixo.

```
for c in range (3):
    bd = {}
    nome = input('Insira seu nome: ')
    sobrenome = input('Insira seu sobrenome: ')
    bd [nome] = sobrenome
print ()
print (bd)
```

A pergunta é, com eu alimento o dicionário usando o **for** (por exemplo) se no final do *loop* ela só me mostra o último *par chave-valor* que eu digitei?

Answer (score 1):

Isso não é uma biblioteca, é um dicionário. Não confunda essas terminologias, bibliotecas também é um termo utilizado em programação, e se refere a algo completamente diferente.

O problema do seu `for`, é que você reinicia seu dicionario toda vez que você intera sobre o laço. Inicie o dicionário fora do laço, isso deve resolver.

```
bd = {}
for c in range (3):
    nome = input('Insira seu nome: ')
    sobrenome = input('Insira seu sobrenome: ')
    bd [nome] = sobrenome
```

Comment: Olá "user145470", estou estudando outras tecnologias que na qual a palavra DICIONÁRIO aparece com frequência, logo ao fazer uma pergunta aqui na comunidade terminei me confundindo. Sei a diferença entre biblioteca e dicionário mas mesmo assim obrigado pela iniciativa. O código deu certo!